# calculating correlation in python

Tags: python, correlation

Im trying to calculate correlation but I'm getting none for the average and min values. I tried to fix it, but couldn't find the error. I'm a beginner to python and don't know a lot. Can you guys please help me
Here is my code;

```
import math
import random

def myAverage(lst):
 sum(lst)/len(lst)
def myStandardDev(lst):
 devitation=[(x - sum(lst)/len(lst) )**2 for x in lst]
 standarddev=sum(devitation)/(len(lst)-1)
 return math.sqrt(standarddev)
def myMin(lst):
min(lst)
def myCorrelation(x,y):
value=1
for i in range(len(x)):
    equation1=(x[i]-(sum(x)/len(x)))/math.sqrt((x[i]-sum(x)/len(x))**2)
    equation2=(y[i]-(sum(y)/len(y)))/math.sqrt((y[i]-sum(y)/len(y))**2)
    value=value*equation1*equation2
return value
def main():
aList=[11,20,30,50,80,90,101,15,125,128,150,185,200,240,260,290]
bList=[14,25,28,45,79,85,121,115,125,256,160,195,230,270,280,330]
cList=bList.copy()
cList.reverse()
dList= [random.randint(1,99) for x in range(len(aList))]
print("Lists:")
print("List A = " + str(aList))
print("List B = " + str(bList))
print("List C = " + str(cList))
print("List D = " + str(dList))
print()
print("List A Average = " + str(myAverage(aList)))
print("Standart Deviation of List A = " + str(myStandardDev(aList)))
print("Minimum of List A = " + str(myMin(aList)))
print()
print("List B Average = " + str(myAverage(aList)))
print("Standart Deviation of List B = " + str(myStandardDev(aList)))
print("Minimum of List B = " + str(myMin(aList)))
print()
print("Correlation of List A and B = " + str(myCorrelation(aList, bList)))
print("Correlation of List A and C = " + str(myCorrelation(aList, cList)))
print("Correlation of List A and D = " + str(myCorrelation(aList, dList)))

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you also include your output, as well as the expected output of the code? A correlation of zero might just mean there is no correlation.

Comment: Also the indentation in your code needs fixing, and you should have spaces between functions.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you omit the `return` keyword, `None` is returned by default. It looks like you need to change your `myAverage` and `myMin` functions to explicitly return the values they compute, i.e.:

```
def myAverage(lst):
    return sum(lst)/len(lst)

def myMin(lst):
    return min(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work, because it is not indented properly. When you begin writing, choose an indentation (2 spaces, 4 spaces, 8 spaces, 1 tabulator), and NEVER use another. I fixed the code for you:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# above line makes you able to execute the python script by double-clicking on it in your Filebrowser (at least on Linux)

import math
import random

# do not omit one single letter in a variable name, your code does not get
# much shorter, it only decreases readability
# Good abbreciations:
# variableName -> varName
# objectNumber -> objNum
# MainWindow -> MainWin
# 
# Bad abbreviations:
# list -> lst
# element -> elmnt
# window -> wndw
# 
# Function / method names should be a description of what they do in 1 to 5 words
# Good function / method names:
# calculate_average / calculateAverage
# average
# get_average / getAverage
# 
# Bad function / method names:
# my_calculate_average
# myAverage
# myFunction is the worst, beacuse it says absolutely nothing about what it does !

def average(list):
# Always put 1 space on each side of an operator (+, -, =, ==, and others) and 1 space after each comma.
# It makes the code more readable
    return sum(list) / len(list)

# Always put 1 free line between two functions / methods / classes

def standardDev(list):
    devitation = [(x - sum(list) / len(list)) ** 2 for x in list]
    standarddev = sum(devitation) / (len(list) - 1)
    return math.sqrt(standarddev)

# omit the following method, just use min(list) directly
# def myMin(list):
#     return min(list)

def correlation(x, y):
    value = 1
    for i in range(len(x)):
        equation1 = (x[i] - (sum(x) / len(x))) / math.sqrt((x[i] - sum(x) / len(x)) ** 2)
        equation2 = (y[i] - (sum(y) / len(y))) / math.sqrt((y[i] - sum(y) / len(y)) ** 2)
        value = value * equation1 * equation2
    return value

def main():
    listA = [11, 20, 30, 50, 80, 90, 101, 15, 125, 128, 150, 185, 200, 240, 260, 290]
    listB = [14, 25, 28, 45, 79, 85, 121, 115, 125, 256, 160, 195, 230,  270, 280, 330]
    listC = bList.copy()
    listC.reverse()
    listD = [random.randint(1, 99) for x in range(len(listA))]
    print("Lists:")
    print("List A = " + str(listA))
    print("List B = " + str(listB))
    print("List C = " + str(listC))
    print("List D = " + str(listD))
    print()
    print("List A Average = " + str(average(listA)))
    print("Standart Deviation of List A = " + str(standardDev(alistA)))
    print("Minimum of List A = " + str(min(listA))
    print()
    print("List B Average = " + str(average(listA)))
    print("Standart Deviation of List B = " + str(standardDev(listA)))
    print("Minimum of List B = " + str(min(listA)))
    print()
    print("Correlation of List A and B = " + str(correlation(listA, listB)))
    print("Correlation of List A and C = " + str(correlation(listA, listC)))
    print("Correlation of List A and D = " + str(correlation(listA, listD)))

# __name__ will be set to "__main__" if the program is run directly, and NOT when
# the program is imported by another program.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```